# In JavaScript How Can I format a date according to the format 2001-08-22 03:04:05.000?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

How can I format a date to the format:   2001-08-22 03:04:05.000

I've been running into a bunch of issues trying to get this to work for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleString('en-CA',{hour12:false}).replace(',','')`